# Is it possible for a shaman to interact with their spirit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, spirits

The shaman's [Spirit](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/Shaman/#Spirit_Su) feature says:

> A shaman forms a mystical bond with the spirits of the world. She forms a lasting bond with a single spirit, which grants a number of abilities and defines many of her other class features.

I can't find any information considering the spirit itself. Is it possible for the shaman to interact with their spirit? Can it help the shaman?

Comment: Just to clarify, you know that shamans have a pet/familiar creature that is possessed by said spirit, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this kind of answer might be frowned upon for its simplicity but here goes:

There is no reason why a DM would be forced to allow you to do that in its game as far as RAW goes ... but there is also no reason why a DM would be forced to disallow it.

Spirits are fickle entities. Unpredictables. Cryptic. A bit alien, too.

They do not answer to the same imperatives or even 'natural laws' than most living creatures.

But they can be "reached", interacted with, especially when there is already a bond established. In fact, there are a lot of adventure hooks that come from interacting with spirits !

As a DM, I would personally try to have fun with that. I'd also strive to make it fun for you as a player, even though I would try to remain true to the 'essence' of the spirit as much as possible, lore wise.

Comment: "I know this kind of answer might be frowned upon for its simplicity" - Nothing wrong with a simple answer! You point out that nothing in the rules (e.g. the class description) guarantees or disallows it, so that's all there is to it. :)